# all go routines are asleep deadlock

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency

I'm in the process of learning how to do concurrency, and I've written this as its own app so that I can port it into a different project once it's working.

The project I'm adding it to will basically send in a RowInfo to a global QueueChannel, and then my workers should pick up this work and process it. If I queue two rows with the same ID, and one of them is currently processing by a worker, I'll remove the duplicate row from the queue (as you can see where I do my "continue" in the dispatcher).

This queueing/worker code will be running on a web server blocking on ListenAndServe, so I want it to always remain running and the workers to always remain actively looking for jobs. I don't want to have to close the channels (unless perhaps I ctrl+C'd the app or something). I suspect the error I'm getting has something to do with not closing channels because that's what a lot of the other threads mentioning this error seem to indicate, but I'm not sure how it relates to the code I have exactly.

Terminal error output:

```
[~/go/src/github.com/zzz/asynch]> go run main.go
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send]:
main.main()
    /home/zzz/go/src/github.com/zzz/asynch/main.go:29 +0x14b

goroutine 5 [select]:
main.diszzzcher(0xc82001a120, 0xc82001a180, 0xc82001a1e0)
    /home/zzz/go/src/github.com/zzz/asynch/main.go:42 +0x21a
created by main.main
    /home/zzz/go/src/github.com/zzz/asynch/main.go:19 +0xb1

goroutine 6 [chan receive]:
main.worker(0xc82001a180, 0xc82001a1e0)
    /home/zzz/go/src/github.com/zzz/asynch/main.go:55 +0x54
created by main.main
    /home/zzz/go/src/github.com/zzz/asynch/main.go:24 +0xf7

goroutine 7 [chan receive]:
main.worker(0xc82001a180, 0xc82001a1e0)
    /home/zzz/go/src/github.com/zzz/asynch/main.go:55 +0x54
created by main.main
    /home/zzz/go/src/github.com/zzz/asynch/main.go:24 +0xf7

goroutine 8 [chan receive]:
main.worker(0xc82001a180, 0xc82001a1e0)
    /home/zzz/go/src/github.com/zzz/asynch/main.go:55 +0x54
created by main.main
    /home/zzz/go/src/github.com/zzz/asynch/main.go:24 +0xf7

goroutine 9 [chan receive]:
main.worker(0xc82001a180, 0xc82001a1e0)
    /home/zzz/go/src/github.com/zzz/asynch/main.go:55 +0x54
created by main.main
    /home/zzz/go/src/github.com/zzz/asynch/main.go:24 +0xf7
exit status 2
```

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

type RowInfo struct {
    id int64
}

var QueueChan chan RowInfo

func main() {
    QueueChan := make(chan RowInfo)
    workerChan := make(chan RowInfo)
    exitChan := make(chan int64)

    go dispatcher(QueueChan, workerChan, exitChan)

    // Start WorkerCount number of workers
    workerCount := 4
    for i := 0; i < workerCount; i++ {
        go worker(workerChan, exitChan)
    }

    // Send test data
    for i := 0; i < 12; i++ {
        QueueChan <- RowInfo{id: int64(i)}
    }

    // Prevent app close
    for {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}

func dispatcher(queueChan, workerChan chan RowInfo, exitChan chan int64) {
    state := make(map[int64]bool)

    for {
        select {
        case job := <-QueueChan:
            if state[job.id] == true {
                continue
            }
            workerChan <- job
        case result := <-exitChan:
            state[result] = false
        }
    }
}

func worker(workerChan chan RowInfo, exitChan chan int64) {
    for job := range workerChan {
        log.Printf("Doing work on job rowInfo ID: %d", job.id)

        // Finish job
        exitChan <- job.id
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The error tells you: all goroutines are asleep, the program has deadlocked.

Now why are all your goroutines asleep? Let's check them one by one:

- the `worker` goroutines: Wait indefinitely for new work on `workerChan`, will not exit until `workerChan` is closed, is asleep whenever it waits for new work
- the `dispatcher` goroutine: Loops forever, selecting over two channels. Will never exit, is asleep while waiting in the `select`
- the `main` goroutine: Loops forever on a `time.Sleep`, will never exit and be asleep most of the time

Typically, in a situation like this, you'd introduce a `chan struct{}` (call it `closing` or something like that) and inclue it in your `select`s. If you want to close the program, just `close(closing)`. The `select` will choose the `<-closing` option, you return the goroutines.
You should also add a `sync.WaitGroup` to be notified when all your goroutines have exited.

Comment: Thank you. So why is Go angry at me about this? Because my program never exits and sleeps indefinitely? Go is upset because my dispatcher function has an infinite loop, my main has an infinite loop, or both, is this against the rules for some reason?

Comment: Well, Go tells you that your program deadlocked, because that's generally unwanted behaviour. It can happen that all goroutines are asleep without having a deadlock (for example when reading a network stream), so the runtime will not complain about that. In your case however, there is no way that your program will ever continue to run

Comment: Right. So I don't think it'll actually be an issue when I add it into my other project, but for now it is. In the mean time, I'll add a closing channel and a WaitGroup like you suggested, hopefully that will fix all of the issues I'm facing here. Thanks again :)